# how to gfsh query from two regions

Tags: gfsh

I have the following data in gfsh DB:

**Region A**:

```
column_X       | column_Y
--------------------------
A=a1,B=b1,C=c1 | D=d1
A=a2,B=b2,C=c2 | D=d2
```

**Region B**:

```
column_M | column_N
----------------------------
A=a1     | H=h1
A=a3     | H=h3
```

I want to query: for all the column_M from region_B, if exist in Region_A, get the result of column_Y

How I can design the query? Thanks.